# is there a possible to clone one server to other server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, clone

I have a server running with Debian 10 . Some process are running in it. I want to have all the same  software operating system/application  to be installed in another server. Is there any way just to clone one server to another. The servers are remote .

For reinstalling the same operating system and the application it will require many hours. I wondered if this can be solved with just cloning the server.

Comment: I'm searching for the same, [this rsync command](https://gist.github.com/sibsfinx/dde1877ab60c185882cd) may do the job...

Answer (score 0):

You can use CloneZilla (https://clonezilla.org/ , free software) to duplicate server. Moreover, it allows to run a lightweight PXE server and TFTP to duplicate up to 253 copies simultaneously. It doesn't limited to Linux, clones many OSes/filesystems.

Comment: any tutorial how to do it ?

Comment: There's an extensive set of docs on their site, along with examples:
https://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-usage/clonezilla-live-usage.php

Comment: CloneZilla requires **physical** access to the server, and OP clearly doesn't have it...

Comment: Yup, Q says "all servers are remote", docs say: "Online imaging/cloning is not implemented yet. The partition to be imaged or cloned has to be unmounted. "